# O GCM entrega as mensagens em tempo real?

Tags: android

Tenho dois aplicativos os quais precisam se comunicar e não quero ficar fazendo requesting ao servidor perguntando se tem algo novo, queria algo que saísse de um app para o outro ou do servidor para o app.
Porém não sei se o GCM(Google cloud message) envia as mensagens em tempo real(ou pelo menos pareça), pois não poderia haver um delay grande entre as mensagens, ah e também é importante manter a ordem que as mensagens foram enviadas elas sejam recebidas.

Answer (score 1):

Segue o que diz a documentação:

> Envie uma mensagem. O servidor de aplicativo envia mensagens para o aplicativo cliente:
>
> 1. O servidor de aplicativo envia uma mensagem para os servidores de conexão GCM.
> 2. O servidor de conexão GCM enfileira e armazena a mensagem se o dispositivo está offline.
> 3. Quando o dispositivo está online, o servidor de conexão GCM envia a mensagem para o dispositivo.
> 4. No dispositivo, a aplicação cliente recebe a mensagem de acordo com a aplicação específica da plataforma. Consulte a documentação
>      específica da plataforma para mais detalhes.

Para maiores informações, por favor, veja a [documentação](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/gcm). 
Saudações!